# Overlapping Slider Image When Resizing Window

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

When resizing my window to check the responsiveness of a Wordpress site that I'm working on I noticed that when moving up to a larger window size, all of a sudden my slider in the header overlaps on top of the content below it. Once you resize the window to a smaller size it corrects itself. What's the deal?

Here's my code for the slider and the content below it:

```
#slideshow_cont { width: 646px; float: left; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; position: relative; }
#slideshow { width: 646px; min-height: 280px; }
.slide_box { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
.slide_box_first { display: block; width: 646px; height: 280px;}
.slide_box img { display: block; width: 646px; height: 280px; }
.slide_box iframe { display: block; width: 646px; height: 280px; }
.slide_box_title { padding: 8px 10px; font-size: 20px; font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #fff; height: 23px; }
.slide_box_title a { color: #222; text-decoration: none; }
.slide_prev { position: absolute; top: 132px; left: 0; cursor: pointer; z-index: 30; }
.slide_next { position: absolute; top: 132px; right: 0; cursor: pointer; z-index: 30; }
.home_box { float: left; width: 313px; background-color: #fff; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px; }
.home_box img, 
.home_box iframe { width: 313px; height: 196px; }
.home_box_last { margin-right: 0; }
.home_box_cont { padding: 5px 5px; text-align: center; }
.home_box_cont h3 { font-size: 20px; margin: 0px 0 10px; font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; text-transform: uppercase; }
.home_box_cont h3 a { color: #222; text-decoration: none; }
.home_box_cont h3 a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #f2664f; }
.home_box_text .home_box_cont { text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; background-color: transparent;}
.archive_title { background-color: #F5F5F5; padding: 10px 8px; margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 16px; }
```

Comment: Can you add the markup for this as well? Or put it into jsFiddle so I can see what's happening? Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Smith, are you looking to see the source code? <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/monument-tours/"><img width="646" height="303" src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Screen-Shot-2014-01-03-at-12.32.54-PM-646x303.png" class="attachment-slide-image wp-post-image" alt="Screen Shot 2014-01-03 at 12.32.54 PM" /></a>

Comment: I don't see corresponding CSS rule names with the `img` tag. If you put the markup and CSS on jsFiddle we can see how it's all getting rendered.